How can I have Lambda A invoke Lambda B within the same VPC using endpoint?
I'm having trouble figuring out how to have Lambda A invoke another Lambda function without using a NAT Gateway when within the same VPC.
I've tried various approaches but none of them seem to work. I have three Security Groups: one for Lambda A, one for Lambda B, and one for the VPC Endpoint.
Here's what I’ve set up:
Lambda A's Security Group (purpose: to invoke and get payload from Lambda B)

Inbound: None
Outbound: VPC Endpoint Security Group
Attached to: Lambda Function (Lambda A)

Lambda B's Security Group (purpose: to receive requests from Lambda A or VPC Endpoint)

Inbound: VPC Endpoint Security Group
Outbound: None
Attached to: Lambda Function (Lambda B)

VPC Endpoint's Security Group (purpose: to connect between the two Security Groups)

Inbound: Lambda A's Security Group
Outbound: Lambda B's Security Group
Attached to: VPC Endpoint

I have enabled DNS hostnames and DNS resolutions. In the VPC Endpoint, I only have the VPC Endpoint Security Group applied and no other Security Groups. Similarly, for both Lambda Functions, I have set up only what is mentioned above.
Regarding the code, I have kept it unchanged and invoke it as if it was not within the VPC.
Code used to invoke:
AmazonLambdaClient amazonLambdaClient = new AmazonLambdaClient(new BasicAWSCredentials("MyAccessKey", "MySecretKey"), RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
    
InvokeResponse mongoDbConnectCentralInsertInvokeResponse = await amazonLambdaClient.InvokeAsync(new InvokeRequest
    {
        FunctionName = "LambdaB",
        Payload = new JObject
        {
            
        }.ToString()
    });

When running a test on Lambda A, it only runs for the duration I set, which is 30 seconds, indicating a common sign of being unable to connect somewhere. I wish CloudWatch Logs would provide a clearer error report instead of just logging the duration.

Is there a particular reason why you have connected the Lambda functions to a VPC? For example, are they accessing Mongo in the VPC? If not, then you should disconnect the Lambda functions from the VPC. This will automatically give them Internet access and it should work nicely.

I have a private endpoint for MongoDB, and it works without any issues. The purpose of having Lambda in the VPC is to ensure that my Lambda functions do not have exposure to the public network and operate solely internally with other Lambda functions.

Oh! If the Lambda functions do not need to access the VPC, then you should disconnect the Lambda functions.  There is no inbound connectivity to Lambda functions, so your security concerns are not necessary.

Thank you for the response. I also have a question: If I don't place the Lambda Function in a VPC, how can I allow my Lambda to access MongoDB through a Private Endpoint, which requires the Security Group of the VPC?

Can you please Edit your Question to clarify/explain your reference to a VPC Endpoint (is it a VPC Endpoint for Lambda?) and what you mean by "access MongDB through a Private Endpoint" (is it "AWS PrivateLink for MongoDB Atlas"?).

If you your Lambda functions need to access resources inside the VPC:
When Lambda A invokes Lambda B, the request goes to the AWS Lambda service, not the actual function.
Therefore, the configuration would normally be:
Lambda A security group

Outbound: Allow all traffic
Inbound: None (Lambda functions can never receive traffic)

Lambda B security group

Outbound: Allow all traffic (more because this is normal, rather than because it is required)
Inbound: None (Lambda functions can never receive traffic)

VPC Endpoints for Lambda

Outbound: None (No traffic ever from the VPC endpoint)
Inbound: Allow all (unless you want to be real strict and only allow from Lambda A)

The configuration you have shown should work, but you say it doesn't. I suspect it might be the Outbound Rules on the Security Group on Lambda A. That's why I suggest allowing "All Outbound" on Lambda A and "All Inbound" on the VPC Endpoint. That's fine from a security perspective because the "Inbound" on the VPC Endpoint can only come from other resources in the VPC (but not the Internet).
If your Lambda functions DO NOT need to access resources inside the VPC:

Do NOT connect them to the VPC
It will work

You mention a concern about exposing the Lambda function to the public network. There is no inbound connectivity to Lambda functions, your concern is not necessary.
